# Gradle ignoring gradle.properties

Tags: java, gradle

I'm just starting out with Gradle and am almost certainly missing something obvious. My system has Java 7 installed as the default but I want all my Gradle projects to be using Java 8 by default. So, I create a `~/gradle.properties` file and put the following in it:

```
$ cat ~/gradle.properties 
org.gradle.java.home = /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

But that doesn't appear to be honored. First, if I try to build my project I get:

```
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> invalid source release: 1.8
```

Also, `gradle --version` gives:

```
$ gradle --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 1.5
------------------------------------------------------------

Gradle build time: Wednesday, October 8, 2014 8:21:39 AM UTC
Groovy: 1.8.6
Ant: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.4 compiled on October 7 2014
Ivy: non official version
JVM: 1.7.0_79 (Oracle Corporation 24.79-b02)
OS: Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 amd64
```

However, if I copy `~/gradle.properties` to my project directory (the directory with the build.gradle file) or if I run `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 gradle assemble` it works. So there's not a syntax error or anything in my gradle.properties file and the JDK path is correct. For some reason the properties file is ignored if it's in my home dir.

Note that I don't have a gradle.properties in my project directory and I also tried putting the file in `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`. I also did a bunch of Google and StackOverflow search and just can't find an answer to this seemingly obvious question.

Comment: I think you want `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`. Otherwise you could just write something in your build file like `task homedir << { println System.getenv('GRADLE_USER_HOME') }` to see your home location (run as `gradle homedir`).

Comment: @RAnders00, thanks for the thought. `gradle homdir` returns `task homedir << { println System.getenv('GRADLE_USER_HOME') }`. Oddly `gradle -g ~ assemble` solves the issue so it appears that gradle did not think my home directory was the gradle home dir. However, gradle does create a `~.gradle` directory for me and moving `gradle.properties` there does not help.I suppose one fix would simply be to set the GRADLE_USER_HOME environment variable.

Comment: Scratch that. I retried the test of putting `gradle.properties` in `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` and now it works. Must have done something wrong in my initial experiment. It seems the gradle docs for the default gradle home location are wrong, at least for the Debian Jessie version of the package.

Comment: doh! To clarify my first comment above, `gradle homedir` returns `null` - that was a cut-and-paste bug (i.e. user error) ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Long story short, gradle reads gradle.properties from `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` **not** `~/gradle-properties` and the docs are pretty clear about that. In short, I'm a knuckle-head.

Comment: Same here. Synced my project 20 times in all the way I could possibly imagine and cursed Android Studio 100 times. Before realizing I called my file `~/.gradle/.gradle.properties`.